# Android apps on ios

Tags: android, ios

How do I install An android app on an iPhone. For android, we enable debugging mode and developer options from settings. How does it work for ios. I need to install an android app on an iPhone just for testing purposes.

Comment: You can't install Android apps on iOS, they're two different OS(s). That's why all companies release separate apps for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install android app on an ios device. Android and IOS are entirely different. They are different operating systems.

For example, Facebook app runs on both android and ios but this doesn't mean that they are same apps. They are developed differently. Ie two different app made ko run on different OS.